# Convert non-null-terminated char* to int

Tags: c++

I am working on some code that reads in a data file. The file frequently contains numeric values of various lengths encoded in ASCII that I need to convert to integers. The problem is that they are not null-terminated, which of course causes problems with atoi. The solution I have been using is to manually append a null to the character sequence, and then convert it.

This is the code that I have been using; it works fine, but it seems very kludgy.

```
char *append_null(const char *chars, const int size)
{
    char *tmp = new char[size + 2];

    memcpy(tmp, chars, size);
    tmp[size + 1] = '\0';

    return tmp;
}

int atoi2(const char *chars, const int size)
{
    char *tmp = append_null(chars, size);

    int result = atoi(tmp);

    delete[] tmp;   

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    char *test = new char[20];
    test[0] = '1';
    test[1] = '2';
    test[2] = '3';
    test[3] = '4';

    cout << atoi2(test, 4) << endl;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: Well, you're in C++, so use the standard library instead of decades-old antiquated approaches with raw buffers.

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using `size + 2` for the allocation, and setting the value for `tmp[size + 1]`? I'd expect you to want to set `tmp[size]` instead...

Comment: @JonSkeet yeah, should be `new char[size + 1]`, `tmp[size] = 0`

Comment: `std::string const tmp(chars, size);
return atoi(tmp.c_str());`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: You are right, I had put that in quite a while ago for reasons I can no longer remember.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int i = atoi(std::string(chars, size).c_str());
```

Comment: @KerrekSB, I prefer to use the simplest solution to a problem no matter which decade it's from. Obviously there are plusses and minuses to every approach.

Comment: Well, it's definitely short and terse but does a strlen, an allocation, a string copy, a C string conversion (no-op on most implementation but could be another realloc/copy), the conversion and then a deallocation.  What a waste a of CPU cycles while one while loop would do the job

Comment: You are in undefined behavior land. The string deallocates before you enter atoi. You need to keep it on the stack and give it a name, instead of creating an anonymous instance.

Comment: @Shloim no, the temporary exists until the end of the statement, i.e. until the call returns.

Answer (score 18):

Fixed-format integer conversion is still well within handroll range where the library won't do:

```
size_t mem_tozd_rjzf(const char *buf, size_t len)        // digits only
{
        int n=0;

        while (len--)
                n = n*10 + *buf++ - '0';

        return n;
}
```

```
long mem_told(const char *buf, size_t len)              // spaces, sign, digits
{
        long n=0, sign=1;

        while ( len && isspace(*buf) )
                --len, ++buf;

        if ( len ) switch(*buf) {
                case '-':       sign=-1;        \
                case '+':       --len, ++buf;
        }

        while ( len-- && isdigit(*buf) )
                n = n*10 + *buf++ -'0';

        return n*sign;
}
```

Comment: i think `mem_tozd_rjzf` is what I need. it's strage that no library functions accepts `len` and so we should write this ourselves...

Comment: @javapowered I hear you, but I think there are so many potential simple utilities that at some point it'd take longer to find/learn/memorize library names than to just write the code -- and Unix traditionally prioritizes human convenience in text, if cycles matter so much just store it raw in the first place seems to be the logic there.

Comment: @javapowered To be honest, I'm not sure what makes this solution superior the one I accepted. Care to explain?

Comment: @cmorse: The answer you accepted has to do a full copy plus heap allocation for each number. This answer just operates on the existing buffer. This here should be *much* faster.

Comment: @cmorse right, this answer is much faster and so applicable to latency-critical code.

Answer (score 12):

In C++11, you can say `std::stoi(std::string(chars, size))`, all from `<string>`.

Comment: While this works, I am in a situation where I cannot count on a compiler that supports C++11 being available.

Comment: I think it is overhead to create a string object specifically just to convert chars to number.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will work, although you should only need `size+1` for appending the null and the null will go at position `size`. Currently, your test code doesn't actually make the function call, but I'll assume that you have a way to determine when the null-terminated characters end. If possibly, I'd recommend making the null termination there so that you don't have to worry about catching cases where you hit an exception before you can deallocate the memory (memory which, honestly, may or may not have been allocated if you start catching exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = "1234";
boost::lexical_cast<int>(str); // 1234
```

Comment: While this works for hardcoded values, it doesn't work for the actual program because all I have is a char* which includes far more data than I actually want to be converted.

Comment: @cmorse: Then extract the data you _do_ want into a `std::string`. "Hardcoded values" have nothing to do with it.

Comment: I was not aware that `std::string` accepted a `size_t` argument.

Comment: @cmorse: Seems you need to find better documentation!

Answer (score 0):

The problem as formulated requires to construct a string given an array of known size, then converting its text into a numeric value.

To convert text into values, C++ has a unified mechanism: streams.
In your case, you can do the following:

```
int i = 0;
std::stringstream(std::string(yourbuffer, yoursize)) >> i;
```

This will completely avoid any plain old C reference.

But, since -as you say- all values come from a file... why just don't read the file itself as a stream via `std::fstream` ?

Answer (score 0):

The question says (emph mine):

> The file frequently contains numeric values of various lengths encoded
>   in ASCII that I need to convert to integers. The problem is that they
>   **are not null-terminated**, which of course causes problems with atoi.

This does not really pose a problem, as, if we look at the docs for [atoi](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) or [strtol](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol), they clearly state:

> Function discards any whitespace characters until first non-whitespace
>   character is found. Then it takes as many characters as possible to
>   form a valid integer number representation and converts them to
>   integer value.

That means, it doesn't matter at all that the numbers aren't null terminated, as long as they are *delimited* by something that stops conversion.

And if they are not delimited, then you have to know the size, and when you know the size, I would also recommend a hand-coded solution like in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17002450/321013).

Comment: The numbers are not delimited by anything.

Comment: @cmorse: That's quite an amazing file format. It would really be nice if you could lay out this format in more detail in the question. First, just out of curiosity on my side. But then, this file format and the accepted answer seem to be in a kind of mismatch. You know, the only time I would have expected such a format would've been when dealing with large amounts of data, and then the accepted answer is a bit suboptimal performance wise.

Comment: Yep, it's an odd file format. Especially since elsewhere in the file numbers are stored directly in binary, instead of in their ASCII form. I'll post some more details on the file format later today.

Comment: http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/MIL-PDF-89020B.pdf
Look at section 3.12c and 3.12d. Oddly, for the actual elevation data, the data is stored directly in "fixed binary."

Comment: @cmorse: Interesting. The fixed-width fields approach doesn't look so odd after all. I think that if you don't care about performance at all, you should go with the std::string approach, otherwise go with the custom fixed-length conversion.

Comment: Right now, when using the `std::string` approach, the program loads 20k+ files in well under 5 seconds. And with the way the program is written, this is the only time that it has convert the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is not answering OP's question, but it helps if your source of `char*` is a `char` array with known size.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rdrohWsx6)

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

// SFINAE fallback  
template<typename T, typename =
    std::enable_if< std::is_pointer<T>::value >
>
int charArrayToInt(const T arr){  // Fall back for user friendly compiler errors
    static_assert(false == std::is_pointer<T>::value, "`charArrayToInt()` dosen't allow conversion from pointer!");
    return -1;
}

// Valid for both null or non-null-terminated char array
template<size_t sz>
int charArrayToInt(const char(&arr)[sz]){
    // It doesn't matter whether it's null terminated or not
    std::string str(arr, sz);
    return std::stof(str);
}


int main() {
    char number[2] = {'4','2'};
    int ret = charArrayToInt(number);
    fmt::print("The answer is {}. ", ret);
    return 0;
}
```